# Apollo Graphql - Default values on network error?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am working with Apollo's Graphql React Client.

I would like to have some "default values" that queries return when they fail to fetch the data, for example, when offline.

I know that I can check if an error occured and populate it manually, but this means that I will have to do it and sync the data between each component that uses the useQuery hook with intersecting results.

I was unable to find anything, but is there some way/best practice to do it?

Thank you